# Count Condicional

Tags: sql-server

Me trabe con un script, les muestro lo que tengo hasta ahora.

Tengo dos tablas, `historial_numeros` e `historial_loterias`
y tengo que contar los que tengan la columna `cod=1`, el problema surge, que pueden tener diferentes cod para cada lotería.

Donde me trabe es que necesito que el `id_historial_numero` `=7` me marque solo una fila no dos, en el ejemplo que tengo  debería figurar solo la fila con el

```
cod=1
```

En la ultima imagen dejo la consulta que tengo hasta ahora.

Desde ya les agradezco la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque no agregar una clausula `where cod = 1`, donde filtres solo los código 1

Comment: Necesito que me marque todos los registros de la tabla historial_numeros por eso no puedo filtrar como me indicas. 

Osea deberían quedar las filas 1,3, 4 y no mostrarse la 2.

Comment: Hola @HM79 creo que tu error esta en la agrupación, solo debieses realizar por las primeras 3, es decir...`GROUP BY id_historial_numero, fecha, t.nombre`

Comment: Pero daría error porque hay columnas que no quedarían contenidas en la agrupación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola si este es el resultado esperado podrías considerar utilizar el query que relaciono.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  id_historial_numero,
  COUNT(CASE
    WHEN cod = 1 THEN 1
  END) AS aciertos
FROM test.dbo.tbl_historial_loterias
GROUP BY id_historial_numero)
SELECT
  HL.id_historial_numero,
  HN.fecha,
  T.nombre AS turno,
  HN.numero,
  HL.aciertos
FROM cte AS HL
INNER JOIN test.dbo.tbl_historial_numeros AS HN
  ON HN.id = HL.id_historial_numero
INNER JOIN test.dbo.tbl_turnos AS T
  ON HN.orden_turno = T.orden;
```

En esta parte del query realizó el COUNT y con este resultado realizó el join con las demás tablas.

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  id_historial_numero,
  COUNT(CASE
    WHEN cod = 1 THEN 1
  END) AS aciertos
FROM test.dbo.tbl_historial_loterias
GROUP BY id_historial_numero)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, era exactamente lo que necesitaba.

PD: Soy nuevo acá, como cierro el post? Saludos.

Comment: Por favor márcala como aceptada, tal como se explica en el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour